# d3.js - Change value for Tooltip with radio button

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, radio-button, tooltip

I am creating a heatmap for Ukraine with some economic indicators.

[The Map](http://economicworldmap.net/impact/d3.html)

Depending on what radio-button is checked, a different colorscale is used to visualize
the different values/indicators.

```
        d3.selectAll('.radio').on('change', function(){

            if (document.getElementById('none').checked) {

                            areas.transition().duration(250)
                                 .attr('fill','steelblue');}

            else if (document.getElementById('agr').checked) {

                            areas.transition().duration(250)
                                 .attr('fill', function(d){return colorScaleagr(d.properties.agricindx)});}
.... and so on.
```

Right now the tooltip (div) only shows the name of the region that is hovered over. I'd like to display also the value for the region, corresponding to the indicator that is selected at the moment. The tooltip's content (the name) is determined within an event-handler of the path/map element.

```
var areas = group.append('path')
                    .attr('d',path)
                    .attr('class', function(d) { return "subunit" + d.id; })
                    .attr('fill','steelblue')
                    .attr('stroke', 'white')
                    .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
                    .attr('opacity','0.8')
                                                       // Hover & Tooltip
                    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                        d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 1);
                        div.transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 1)                          
                        div.html(d.properties.name )
                           .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 330)  + "px")
                           .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1] + 15)  + "px");
                        })

                    .on("mousemove", function(d) {                                                  
                        div.html(d.properties.name)
                           .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 350) + "px")
                           .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1] + 25)  + "px");

                        })  

                    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                        d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.8);                           
                        div.transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 0)                          
                        });
```

So my question now is: How can i take into account the status of the radio-button,
whithin the path-element (area) , since the data for the single entities (regions)
is stored there. If I try to manipulate the tooltip within the radio-buttion selection, the data is not available to me. I hope I made myself understand :). I appreciate any help.

Comment: could you put your code in sth like http://jsfiddle.net/? I couldn't see anything from your link and difficult to say what wrong happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do so here's an attempt of what I would do:

1. format you data as an object with key/value pairs as follow: 'none': 10, 'agr': 4, etc...
2. Store the key from the different radio buttons as a global variable that you update on the radio change function.
3. When creating your tooltip on the mouseover function, print the correct value by calling d[key], i.e. d['agr'].

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, that was not exactly the solution, but gave me the proper idea. I just put all the data into an array, with several subarrays containg the values for the single indicators. Since every entity has an id, i could just refer to the array, using the corresponding id.